# Attach file stored in data/data/com.package/files/

Tags: java, android, private

I want to attach a file that is in
data/data/com.example.XXXX/files/THISFILE.txt

but first I should export it to the SD in order to attach it,
I have this code below but "hello.txt" file is not created.. So I can't attach it.

```
public class exportar extends Activity {


String from = "/data/data/com.example.XXXXXX/files/THISFILE.txt";
String to = "/sdcard/hello.txt";


public static boolean copyFile(String from, String to) {
    try {
        int bytesum = 0;
        int byteread = 0;
        File oldfile = new File(from);
        if (oldfile.exists()) {
            InputStream inStream = new FileInputStream(from);
            FileOutputStream fs = new FileOutputStream(to);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1444];
            while ((byteread = inStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                bytesum += byteread;
                fs.write(buffer, 0, byteread);
            }
            inStream.close();
            fs.close();
        }
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);




   Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    i.setType("message/rfc822");
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"XXX");
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT   , ("XXX"));


     String file = "file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/hello.txt";


    Uri uri = Uri.parse(file);
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);



    finish();
    try {
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "xxxx."));



    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {


        finish();
    }
}
}
```

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

EDITED 1

I have changed

```
String from = "/data/data/com.example.XXXXXX/files/THISFILE.txt";
String to = "/sdcard/hello.txt";
```

to

```
File ruta_data = Environment.getDataDirectory();
File from = new File(ruta_data.getAbsolutePath(), "com.example.aa/files/THISFILE.txt");


File ruta_sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File to = new File(ruta_sd.getAbsolutePath(), "Hello.txt");
```

I put  `getDataDirectory()` because it is in data/data/ but I don't know what should I do if it is n data/data/com.example.aa/files/THISFILE.txt

The ruta_sd is correct if I want to copy it to the root of the SD?

Comment: Never hardcode paths, as both `from` and `to` will fail on various devices. Also, never use string concatenation to build paths -- use the proper `File` constructor, and use `Uri.fromFile()` to create a `Uri` from a `File` when you need a `Uri`. Always use the same value for paths, rather than rebuilding `to` as `file`. Finally, you may need to `sync()` when you are done writing: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/12/saving-data-safely.html

Comment: I have eited my question, I changed the STRING to FILE s it fine now? I don't know how to set the path of the files can you help me?